# Kafka consumer Spring Data or Http REST API

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I have the choice to persist a Kafka message in database directly using Spring Data JPA, or make an HTTP POST call to another REST API after consuming.

Could you please tell me what's the best choice?

Comment: Depends on your use case. We don't have nearly enough information to answer that question.

Comment: @Jorn my use cas is just get the message from kafka & persist it in the Database

Comment: If there's absolutely no other difference, then why add the extra indirection via a REST API? Just persist to the database.

Comment: It's like asking: "I need bread, should I drive to the bakery directly or through the next town over?"

Comment: You could use Kafka Connect instead of writing your own Java/Spring code, by the way

Comment: If you control the code of that REST API, you could also put your consumer there instead of making any HTTP calls

Comment: Just persist on database, keep it simple.

Comment: @Jorn im asking the question becaue i have already the API developped that persist the object.and i want to know if i could use it instead of developping all the layers Entity,repository,service.. plus datasource conf in my kafka consumer

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes i have the control on the api project. it's a good practise to combine api (synchronous call) & kafka (asynchronous call) in the same project ?

Comment: Still, how do you expect *us* to make that choice? Either option is viable. *You* need to pick one based on requirements.

Comment: Follow S of SOLID principle, let the HTTP API manage the lifecycle of the entity if it's built for that. But I'm very skeptical about your architecture in terms of domain responsibility segregation.

Comment: @Jorn my question was clear : if the both solutions are valid or not or i could choose one instead of the other. not asking you to choice at my place. regards

Comment: It's a practice commonly done. Good or not, we cannot decide for you. Kafka Steams can be both a REST API and processor (see docs on Interactive Queries), for example. Similarly for ksqlDB

Comment: @James I'm going to repeat myself because it's important to get this point across: There is no "best" choice in a vacuum. And since you haven't defined any parameters, there's not much we can do for you. And that's why all answers here are pure speculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about your problem in terms of availability and consistency.

What happens if the database is unreachable (say, it's going through an upgrade), then will you end up losing events? In that scenario, a highly available HTTP API seems like a better choice.

Alternatively, you've not mentioned what the API actually does with the record. Is it writing to the same database? If so, you're only adding latency to any process that reads from the database (eventual consistency). In that case, directly writing to the database would be quicker, with the tradeoff of availability, mentioned above, which could be addressed by running a distributed database cluster.

You could alternatively use Kafka Streams to create a RocksDB table on disk, rather than use JPA.